# Typeahead select not adding value to input

Tags: jquery, ajax, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I'm using a Typeahead and Bloodhound feature that provides some suggestions. When a user selects a suggestion I want to assign the input with that value.

However, this doesn't seem to work in its current iteration.

```
<input id="fruit" name="fruit" value=""/>

$('#fruit').bind('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion){
    var name = suggestion.label;
    $("#fruit").typeahead('val', name);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: create jsfiddle if possible, by adding all files + code  into it

Comment: What value do you want to assign to which input? What does your typeahead declaration look like? Have you checked out [the docs](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/)?